# Problems with Relaxed Binding and spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot 2.0 M7. I'm trying to use the Binder API to get a hold of a map of properties.

I have the following use case:
I have a number X of properties that have a specific prefix, XXX, for example, that prefix is followed by a dynamic string that we'll name a bean, and this property is followed by other keys they will the bean properties. The complete example is:

```
XXX.BEANA.PROPERTYA
XXX.BEANA.PROPERTYB
XXX.BEANB.PROPERTYA
```

and so on...

The thing here is that this can be configured in many ways (with an underscore instead of dots, all caps, etc...), so we need Relaxed binding

I created a test, and on the test, I use a MockEnvironment, I wrote the properties keys in different ways (All caps, lower caps, separated by dots ,separated by underscore and a combination of this) to check if my code is working properly. But when I set with an underscore instead of dots (XXX_BEANA_PROPERTYA for example), the binder won't find my properties. In the spring boot relaxed binding wiki for spring boot 2, environment variables section (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#environment-variables) it tells that:

```
Environment variables are bound by lowercasing and replacing _ with ... 
For example: SPRING_JPA_DATABASEPLATFORM=mysql results in the property spring.jpa.databaseplatform=mysql
```

But looking through a debugger it seems the property are still using the underscore all caps syntax.

The way that I am configuring the Binder is:

```
Binder.get(this.enviroment).bind("XXX", Bindable.mapOf(String.class, Object.class)).ifBound(this::doSomething);
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: What are the different ways that you set the properties? The mapping that you have described is only applied to property sources named systemEnvironment or ending with "-systemEnvironment".

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant was how I wrote the property key, a quick example would be:  x_beana_propertya, x.beana.propertya, X_BEANA_PROPERTYA, etc...